# In R, plot the average number of unique events per year

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

**Background**

I've got an R dataframe `d`:

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","a","b","b","c","c","d"),
                event = c("R2","R2","O99","B4","B4","A24","A24","J15"),
                service_date = as.Date(c("2011-01-01","2011-07-12","2013-12-23","2011-04-27","2012-01-01","2012-07-12","2012-12-23","2013-04-27")),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>% arrange(service_date, ID)
```

It looks like this (I've `arrange`d it by `service_date` and `ID` so it's easier to look at):

[image: d]

**The Problem**

I'm trying to visualize, using `geom_bar`, how many distinct (i.e. non-repeating or non-duplicated) events there are in this dataframe in each year, but I'm having a little trouble.

**Desired Result**

To give a better idea of what I want, take a look at the first year in `d`, which is 2011. You see 3 rows, but only **2** distinct events, R2 and B4, because R2 is repeated once in row 3. In the bar chart, then, I'd like the first bar to represent 2011 and show **2**.

If you do the counts for the other 2 years, you get the same result each time. So what I want is a bar chart with 3 bars representing 2011, 2012, and 2013, each with a height of **2**, representing the count of unique `events` in the dataframe across all `ID`s.

**EDIT** I'm seeing that I wasn't clear in my description of the desired result. Apologies to readers! Here's a crude visual depiction done in Excel:

[image: desired]

**What I've Tried**

The code I'm trying to fiddle with is something like this:

```
ggplot(data = d) + geom_bar(aes(x = service_date, y = n_distinct(event)), stat = "identity")
```

But that's getting me an odd result:

[image]

I'm not married to `ggplot` for this, any plotting function will do.

Comment: If you want `n_distinct` to operate over groups, you have to tell it to do so. Right now you're just assigning the number of distinct event values in the whole data frame to your y-scale; nothing in your code says to do otherwise

Comment: Okay, thanks. Let me see if I can work `group_by` in there somehow.

Comment: Hey @akrun sorry I updated my post with a visual of how I wanted it to be displayed, see if that helps you! (Also, I haven't downvoted you at all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can extract the `year` from the `Date` class 'service_date' column, create the new column 'n' with number of distinct elements from 'event', and then do the barplot

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
d %>% 
   group_by(year = year(service_date))  %>% 
   summarise(n = n_distinct(event)) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = year, y = n)) + 
     geom_col()
```

-output

### [image]

The OP used `n_distinct` on the entire column 'event' and not grouped by 'ID', thus it is returning a single value